# Too many re renders - React - Filter Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [avaliador, setAvaliador] = useState("");
  const [avaliadoresList, setAvaliadoresList] = useState([]);
  const [DataResultsTotal, setDataResultsTotal] = useState([]);

  const filters = useSelector((state) => state.filter);

  // not all consts is here, only to show the problem

  const fetchData = async (token) => {
    try {
      const responseResult = await axios.get(
        "http://apicall/example/all",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );

      setDataResultsTotal(responseResult.data);
      setAreaProgs(responseResult.data.length);

      // and continuous some calc to send to updates the state and show to the user
      });
      setError(responseResult.data.erro);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("something wrong", erro);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    fetchData(token);
  }, [token]);

  const handleChangeSelect = (event) => {
    setAvaliador(event.target.value);
    dispatch(updateFilters({ ["name"]: event.target.value }));
  };

  const shouldDisplay = (lev) => {
    let matchesSearchText = lev.noEncarregado
      .toUpperCase()
      .includes(filters.noEncarregado);

    // let matchesCategory = lev.id.toLowerCase().includes(filters.ids);
    //  filters.ids.length > 0
    //   ? filters.ids.some((id) => id == lev.category)
    //    : true;
    return matchesSearchText;
  };

  const filteredData = DataResultsTotal.filter((lev) => shouldDisplay(lev));
  setDataResultsTotal(filteredData); // the error goes here

  return (
    <Box
      paddingLeft={isOpen ? "80px" : "200px"}
      bgcolor={`${colors.slate[100]}`}
    >
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6}>
          <Box>
            <Typography
              variant="h4"
              sx={{
                fontWeight: "bold",
                marginLeft: "20px",
                marginTop: "20px",
              }}
            >
              text title
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              sx={{
                marginLeft: "20px",
                marginTop: "5px",
                marginBottom: "20px",
              }}
            >
              anotr text
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          sm={6}
          md={6}
          lg={6}
          marginTop={"20px"}
          marginBottom={"10px"}
        >
          <Box
            display={"flex"}
            alignItems={"center"}
            height={"100%"}
            justifyContent={"flex-end"}
          >
            <DownloadBtn DownText={true} />
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
          <Box sx={{ mx: "10px", my: "5px" }}>
            <Box sx={{ minWidth: 150 }}>
              <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
                  texttt
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                  id="demo-simple-select"
                  value={avaliador}
                  label="Avaliador"
                  onChange={handleChangeSelect}
                >
                  {avaliadoresList.map((avaliador) => (
                    <MenuItem key={avaliador} value={avaliador}>
                      {avaliador}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
          <Box sx={{ mx: "10px", my: "5px" }}>
            <CardHome
              size="h7"
              sizedesc="h3"
              name="text"
              icon={
                <ListAltOutlinedIcon
                  sx={{
                    fontSize: "28px",
                    color: `${colors.greenAccent[800]}`,
                  }}
                />
              }
              description={<Counter from={0} to={showfiltereddata} />}
            />
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Well, I'm trying to filter something with a select with Material-UI and Redux, everything is ok with the filter, but I'm not getting how I recalculated the filtered data and show to the user.

In this code, I will get the state from Redux, bring to the page, compare with the calculated data that's becoming from API call, and save it on a const, but I need to recalculated this filtered data again, but when I try to do that, throws "too many re renders", and I know that why happens, but I don't know the better approach to deal with it, maybe two `useEffects`?

Comment: Why are you calling `setToken` every time `token` changes in the `useEffect()`?

Comment: I've fixed the indentation. It looks like the brackets near your try/catch are unmatched, Could you fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unintentional side effect.

```js
const filteredData = DataResultsTotal.filter((lev) => shouldDisplay(lev));
setDataResultsTotal(filteredData); // <-- unconditional state update!
```

`filteredData` is a new array reference each time the component renders, and each time a state update is enqueued and triggers a component rerender.

Just compute and use directly the derived `filteredData` value, ***don't*** use it to update the source of truth, e.g. the `filters` and `DataResultsTotal` state. Remove the unintentional side-effect `setDataResultsTotal(filteredData);` from the code.

Example:

```js
const shouldDisplay = (lev) => lev.noEncarregado
  .toUpperCase()
  .includes(filters.noEncarregado);

const filteredData = DataResultsTotal.filter(shouldDisplay);
```

or

```js
const filteredData = React.useMemo(() => {
  const shouldDisplay = (lev) => lev.noEncarregado
    .toUpperCase()
    .includes(filters.noEncarregado);

  return DataResultsTotal.filter(shouldDisplay);
}, [DataResultsTotal, filters]);
```

Render the UI from the computed `filteredData` value instead of the `DataResultsTotal` state now.

Comment: i updated the code with your changes, but i need to recalculated the values again, and that's the problem, i don't know why, if it's like a live filter table, this way works because i dont need to recalculated the values...

Comment: @lucasbarbosa Sorry, what values need to be recalculated? The code you shared is  just filtering a source array, right? The only thing being "calculated" here is the filtered result based on the source array and the filtering value.

Comment: In the first part, i set on state DataResultsTotal, all the values coming from the API, and after that i need to "calculated" or "filter" in setResults(), and showed to the Users, but when a user choose another value in Select, i need to do this again, get the value from user, check with redux(this part is working) and returning the filtered data, and after that i need to recalculated or refiltered, because i can't display directly to the user the values that i dont have, for example, the count of some property, i have to call SetResults again to do that, but this cause problems...

Comment: @lucasbarbosa The entire idea of computing the derived filtered data is so that you ***don't*** mutate the source information and need to refetch it again. Just use the  derived `filteredData` value in the UI instead of `DataResultsTotal` state. Maybe I've misunderstood your code. Are you saying that after the user selects a filter value that `fetchData` needs to be re-run so the `DataResultsTotal` state is updated?

Comment: For example, after user choose the filter value, the filtereddata will be like: 10 results over 30, because i filtered, thats correct, but where i can get with this 10 results that derived from initial api call, this value inside setResults?

Comment: i need to get filtereddata and do this again, the filtered again and after that show to the users...and i dont have it a property in the filter because in the initial api call dont have it this value, i filter after and show to the users, after that i filter the initial api call and get filtered data and filter again to get this "calc" again...and finally show to the users

Comment: @lucasbarbosa Sorry, what am I missing here? Just use `filtereddata` where you need it after it is computed from the set/updated `DataResultsTotal` state when the `useEffect` hook runs and fetches/sets it and whatever `filters` value the user is setting in the Redux store. If new `DataResultsTotal` data isn't being fetched then I don't see what needs to be recalculated. Don't overwrite the `DataResultsTotal` state with the filtered data as this removes data from the source of truth after it was fetched.

Comment: thanks for the help, in fact i just solve it filtering like u say, and after that i filter again to do the "calc" and just works, i was stuck thinking in recalculating in the beggining, but not needed, thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I agree with the second half of your statement, but can you explain why state shouldn't be updated inside useEffect()?

To answer [Codebling‘s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675721/codebling) question and your’s too I suppose, let’s analyze your code.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  fetchData(token);
}, [token]);
```

The behavior of the code above is that on initial render, the subroutine in the `useEffect` runs, `setToken` then mutates `token` and `token` is a dependency of the `useEffect` so the `useEffect` will run again and again and… *what you have created is an infinite loop.*

Comment: Almost... we don't know what `token` or `setToken` are in the OPs code snippet, but it doesn't appear to be any local state, so updating it won't trigger a component rerender. OP certainly hasn't provided a complete enough [mcve] to say with certainty this is the problem and that you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not keep the token in state.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    fetchData(token);
  }, []);
```

You shouldn't update state in an effect if the state is a dependency of that effect.

Comment: I agree with the second half of your statement, but can you explain why state shouldn't be updated inside `useEffect()`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with enqueueing a state update in the `useEffect` hook. Unconditionally updating a dependency however is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    fetchData(token);
  }, [token]);
```

this is causing this error to occur, i think what you should do is,

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    fetchData(token);
  }, [token]);

useEffect(() => {
    setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
}, []);
```

this is also not perfect solution but as i dont know your full use context i can only provide this as solution that might work!

Comment: It might be helpful to explain how that block is causing the rerender